# Create a file object for testing purposes

Tags: javascript, file, reactjs, mocha.js

I have a React component with a callback function on a file input. When the file input changes, it runs this method, which uses the Papa library to parse the file object.

```
handleFile(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    this.state.filename = file.name;

    this.setState({
        filename: file.name,
        isParsing: true,
    });

    Papa.parse(file, {
        complete: this.parseComplete.bind(this),
    });
}
```

I want to be able to test this method with different types of file inputs to test invalid/valid CSV file responses. The way I was thinking about doing this is like:

```
const testFile = new File(...add some valid data here?);
const testEvent = {target: {files: [testFile]}};

handleFile(testEvent);
// test for response behavior
```

But I'm not sure how to go about creating a mock CSV file using the Javascript constructor. Any suggestions?